# RPC errors raised by each command

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

Coming from [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59683/can-i-find-a-list-of-possible-error-codes-and-their-meanings-for-bitcoin-cli), is there any comprehensive collection of what errors can each RPC command return?

For example. Let's say I want to run `getbestblockhash` or `getblockcount`. I'm unsure about what errors to expect. Furthermore, I'm unsure if there's a generic error code that can be return in many cases (`RPC_MISC_ERROR` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Coming from [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59683/can-i-find-a-list-of-possible-error-codes-and-their-meanings-for-bitcoin-cli), is there any comprehensive collection of what errors can each RPC command return?
>
> For example. Let's say I want to run `getbestblockhash` or `getblockcount`. I'm unsure about what errors to expect.

I don't think that such documentation  exists. You would have to read the source code for a particular RPC. Additionally, since some functions are shared between RPCs and can return specific errors, it may not be easy to enumerate all of the errors.

> Furthermore, I'm unsure if there's a generic error code that can be return in many cases (`RPC_MISC_ERROR` for example).

If there's an error which doesn't have its own specific catching and checking (i.e. an exception is thrown that the RPC doesn't catch), then `RPC_MISC_ERROR` will be returned.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll wait a bit to see if someone has done the heavy lifting :( Am I at least safe to assume that any unexpected error will default to `RPC_MISC_ERROR` ?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that unexpected errors default to `RPC_MISC_ERROR`.